# need to json_encode a PHP array in a particular way

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Ok, what i have is a PHP array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => 1
            [value] => Value example
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => 10
            [value] => Value example 2
        )
    [...]
)
```

Now, if i `json_encode()` this array, what i get is:

```
[
    Object { label="1", value="Value example" },
    Object { label="10", value="Value example 2" },
    ...
]
```

But to use it in [jQuery Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) i need the array to be like this:

```
[
    { label="1", value="Value example" },
    { label="10", value="Value example 2" },
    ...
]
```

I've read tons of pages without finding a solution...can someone help?

**UPDATE FOR PETER:**

Here's my code:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($temp as $tmp) {
    $results[] = array(
        'label' => $tmp['id'],
        'value' => $tmp['it']
    );
};
echo json_encode($results);
```

If it may be useful, `$temp` array is generated from the following Wordpress function:

```
$wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

**UPDATE FOR PETER 2**

SCRIPT:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var temp_array = function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'action': 'autocomplete_finder',
                'data' : request.term,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //response(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    };
    $('#containing').autocomplete({
        source: temp_array,
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            console.log('test')
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="containing" style="width: 98%">
```

Comment: this is not `json_encode` output. there are `:` characters instead `=` and there is no "Object". [proof](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RCt8Wq). Also `json_encode` is perfectly fine for jquery autocomplete. Also `=` is not correct JSON. Please show us your code.

Comment: @Peter i've updated the question for you.

Comment: it looks ok. can you show me actual result of "json_encode"? I am guessing you copy-pasted data from browser console which is not raw text you send to browser. I think your PHP code is fine, there is some problem on javascript side

Comment: Yes, i've copy-pasted the code from the console. The actual result taken from the browser output seems to be the correct format that jQuery Autocomplete needs. Then why the autocomplete is not working? `[{"label":"1","value":"Value example"},{"label":"10","value":"Value example 2"},...]`

Comment: make sure your selector `$('#whatever')` is correct. this trivial mistake is often hard to find. also can you show how do you initiate autocomplete in js?

Comment: @Peter updated again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized what simple mistake you did

Switch `label` with `value`:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($temp as $tmp) {
    $results[] = array(
        'label' => $tmp['it'],
        'value' => $tmp['id']
    );
};
echo json_encode($results);
```

and it will works

your array should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Value example
            [value] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Value example 2
            [value] => 10
        )
    [...]
)
```

Comment: i tried and there's no difference...why switching them should make any difference?

Comment: @Mariano because it gives you hint for `label` not for `value`

Comment: OMG...what a stupid mistake...now it's working (i've hardly refreshed the browser since the first comment)...thanks a lot!